# NSXMLParser - only need to read from parser:foundCharacters: in certain elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, macos, cocoa

This is my first time working with XML, but I am trying to use NSXMLParser to parse my school's calendar XML (which can be seen [here](http://whs.wayland.k12.ma.us/syndication/rss.aspx?serverid=1036540&userid=5&feed=calendarevents&key=2RHXqHYKF8vPbqQ7RCDPfuU7gMLJdOA%2f%2fLmSBT0aaMvR1GAWYpIQBnxFytIxnWKRTs7jT%2fY5T%2brtDb0SJQxJuA%3d%3d&calendar_id=1062637&v=2.0)).

For my purposes I only need to get the text between the title and description tags of items.

Through what I've read in the mac developer library it seems as though the parser sends notifications to the delegate every time it hits an element (with the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attribute:` method) and when it hits text (with the `parser:foundCharacters:` method). While i can see how you could do things only for certain elements with the didStartElement... method, I can't see how I could get the text with the foundCharacters: method only for the certain elements that I want. Is there any way to do this, or am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: You can't stop `foundCharacters` from being called, but you can have `didStartElement` set some ivar if the `elementName` is one of the two elements you care about, and then have `foundCharacters` look at that ivar to determine whether it should do something with those characters, or whether it should just `return` and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, so would something like setting a BOOL to YES in `didStartElement` and to NO in `didEndElement` and then checking it in `foundCharacters` work?

Comment: Yep, that would do it. Or given that `foundCharacters` generally only appends characters to a mutable string, I just have `didStartElement` initialize a mutable string pointer if the element name is one of the ones I care about and otherwise sets the mutable string pointer to `nil`. There are lots of ways to skin the cat here. But the idea is the same: `didStartElement` determines if we're parsing an element we care about and sets the appropriate class properties, `foundCharacters` appends depending upon those class properties, `didEndElement` saves depending upon the element name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop `foundCharacters` from being called, but you can have `didStartElement` set some class property if the `elementName` is one of the two elements you care about, and then have `foundCharacters` look at that class property to determine whether it should do something with those characters, or whether it should just immediately return and effectively discard the characters it received.

For example, this is a simplified version of my parser:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // if the element name is in my NSArray of element names I care about ...

    if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName])
    {
        // then initialize the variable that I'll use to collect the characters.

        self.elementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // if the variable to collect the characters is not nil, then append the string

    if (self.elementValue)
    {
        [self.elementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    // if the element name is in my NSArray of element names I care about ...

    if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName])
    {
        // step 1, save the data in `elementValue` here (do whatever you want here)

        // step 2, reset my elementValue variable

        self.elementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: Thank you! Completely get it now.

Comment: I thought about setting a BOOL value when it comes to an element I care about, almost same logic as yours. I am really surprised why there is no protocol method to handle picking up exactly the element I want.

Comment: @Malloc Agreed. While I could have `didStartElement` initialize some `BOOL` flag too, it is a little redundant if you're also only initializing `elementValue` when you have an element you want to parse, already. In answer to you the "surprised there is not protocol to do this" argument, I get that, too, and my generic parser (from which the above snippet derives) does precisely that. I always cringe when I see parser implementations that have a bunch of business logic buried in the parser. You should have a simple interface with a callback for the elements that the app cares about.